# How to get iPhone, not iPad view in Interface Builder

Tags: ipad, interface-builder, size, nib

At first, I was not able to build a new blank project to iPhone using the new XCode 3.2 beta. I edited the project settings and was able to build the blank app to iPhone simulator.

However, when I open the nib for the project in IB and click the view, it opens an iPad size view.

How do I get the right sized view to work on in IB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmd+I on your project, find the setting containing the string "iPad", change it to "iPhone".

[image]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://x69.xanga.com/80df8a3648d37265279987/w211546347.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

in InterfaceBuilder select your view, then File->Create iPhone/iPod touch Version